# Custom SQL query to retrieve info

Tags: ee1

Do you guys know of a library where there's sample queries to retrieve info like how many pages are in a specific site ect?

What I mean is a custom select statement.

Thanks, 
Dan

Comment: This question needs significant clarification. Are you using the pages module? Is this multisite? Hell, did ee1 even have multisite? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example in PHP (within EE of course) here, this will count all posts in a channel, and I assume you drive your pages of a channel too :

```
<?php
  //count all Open posts in Channel 1, of site ID 1
  $res = ee()->db->select("COUNT(*) AS 'total'")
             ->from('channel_entries')
             ->where('status','open')
             ->where('channel_id','1')
             ->where('site_id','1')
             ->get();
  $totalChannel1Posts = 0;
  if ( $res->num_rows() > 0 ) {
    $res = array_unshift($res->result_array());
    $totalChannel1Posts = $res['total'];
  }
```

Is that any help?? Of course you can work out the query itself from the above too.

Otherwise, are you looking for some sort of site crawler? Because EE itself has no concept of a 'page', but rather templates that could be static or dynamic pages, a router and channels to store similar data, which in turn use a dynamic template to provide a new 'page' with entry specific data...

You might be best off using something like google to count your pages!